# How to concat pipe result with next command?

Tags: bash

I would like to run something like :

```
pwd | echo "++++ working at : $x"
```

and the $x variable would show the current directory. I've tried a kind of $(...) stuff with no success.

It has to be in one line to be run in a Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could use xargs

```
pwd | xargs -I{} echo "++++ working at : {}"
```

Alternatively you could just not use a pipe and use a subshell

```
echo "++++ working at : $(pwd)"
```

Answer (score 3):

BASH gives you an env variable called `PWD` denoting current working directory  hence there is no need to call any external utility just use:

```
echo "++++ working at : $PWD"
```

Answer (score 1):

backticks to the rescue!

```
echo "++++ working at : " `pwd`
```

backticks mean: put the command output right here in the command line as argument(s)

Comment: Use `$(...)` instead of backticks.